# Angular gestures and angular mobile ui accordion collision

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, collision

I noticed, when you nest an acordion (angular-mobile-ui) within div with hm-[whatever] directive (angular-gestures), acordion will stop working properly (cant expand or collapse). It's browser independent. E.g.

```
<div hm-swipe-right=('foo()')>
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Example above will not work, but example below will do:

```
<div hm-swipe-right=('foo()'> </div>
<div>
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Do you know how to fix that? I'm afraid there is a collision between angular-gesture and angular-mobile-ui. Anybody solved this?

**Edit1**: It is possible to use ngTouch instead angular-gestures (ng-swipe-right directive) - which works properly, but it doesnt solve the problem with angular-gestures.

Comment: What is hm? I use ng prefix like ng-swipe-right

Comment: hm is a shortcut (prefix) for "hammer" angular plugin (https://github.com/monospaced/angular-hammer) which extend touch events (in my case - better beheavior of touch events). It's awhile ago I describe this strange behavior, meanwhile I use different aproach not remember what, but I have never solved that problem.